# KonvaJS: How to connect two shapes with an arrow so that arrow can be moved to new position using mouse?

Tags: konvajs, konva

I have connected two custom shapes with arrow in konva. But after the connection, the arrow remains static. I cant move it to point to new position. Instead I will have to delete the arrow and redraw it. How to create an arrow that can be moved in any position(not just from pointer)

[image: before moving the arrow with cursor]original

[image: before moving the arrow with cursor] after moving the arrow with cursor

Comment: Have you tried a Transformer ?

Comment: yes. But transformer is not producing desired behavior.

Comment: I need to move arrow like it moves in this https://app.diagrams.net/